# Docker create Laravel image

Tags: laravel, docker

I am new to docker.

I want to put Laravel in my image. How to write a dockerfile correctly for, if it’s not difficult for anyone, can they throw off the finished one? (Out-of-the-box Laravel images are not needed). It is necessary that I then register volume / app: / app in compose and be able to edit the project

I try this, but is not work for me:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www
VOLUME /var/www/
# Add docker php ext repo
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

# Install php extensions
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd memcached

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    lua-zlib-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    nginx

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www 
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy code to /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www

# add root to www group
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage

# Copy nginx/php/supervisor configs
RUN cp docker/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN cp docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini
RUN cp docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# PHP Error Log Files
RUN mkdir /var/log/php
RUN touch /var/log/php/errors.log && chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

# Deployment steps
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN chmod +x /var/www/docker/run.sh
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/docker/run.sh"]
```

Comment: What mean “not work”?

Comment: If you are mounting your local filesystem as a volume on docker and you run `composer install` on your local filesystem then you don't need to do anything to the image because Laravel will already be installed in your local filesystem

Comment: If I run docker run everything works. But if I then add compose to the docker, then an error occurs that it cannot find the bash script

Comment: Do I need a supervisor?